# Why does my footer go far away?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two questions but the main one is why my footer goes far away in the bottom even if I didn't define a size for the body and no margins or whatever you want between my blocks "footer" and "section"?

The other question is why even if I'm in relative position when I zoom in or out on the page, the top of block "nav" and "section" are not always align?

---

```css
p, li
{
 text-align: justify;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                             POLICES                                                */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ambleregular';
    src: url('Amble-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Amble-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Amble-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Amble-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Amble-Regular-webfont.svg#ambleregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                         CORPS DE LA PAGE                                           */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.police
{
    font-family: 'ambleregular', "Times New Roman", Georgia, Arial, Verdana, "Courier New", sans-serif;
}

#Bloc_principal
{
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: purple;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                             EN - TETE                                              */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

header
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}

#logo img
{
    width:56px;
    height: auto;
    border:2px black solid;
    float: left;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                MENU                                                */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.menu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.menu_perso
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu_cote
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu_perso ul, .menu_cote ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

aside
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

footer
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                CORPS                                               */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.contenu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 622px;
    position: relative;
    top: -363px;
    left: 265px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>GE-tools</title>
    </head>

    <body class="police">
     <div id="Bloc_principal">
      <header>
       <div id="logo">
        <img src="GE_tool.PNG" alt="Logo">
       </div>
       <h1 class="titre_principal">GE-Tools</h1>
      </header>

      <section class="menu">
       <nav class="menu_perso">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">My Mails</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>

       <nav class="menu_cote">
        <h1>Tools</h1>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">bbbbbbbbbbb</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ccccccccccc</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ddddddddddd</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">eeeeeeeeeee</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">fffffffffff</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>

       <aside>
        <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
       </aside>
      </section> 
      <section class="contenu">
       <h1>Welcome in GE-tool</h1>

       <p>Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem sed sibi vicissim velut ad perpendiculum aemulas: Caesaream, quam ad honorem Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas.</p>

       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

 
                At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>

       <p>Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem sed sibi vicissim ad honorem Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas.</p>
      </section>

      <footer>
       <p>Copyright GE - Tools corporation 2017©</p>
      </footer>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `position: relative; top: -363px;`. Instead of using that, you should use `float: left;` and `float: right`.

So you change:

```
.menu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

to

```
.menu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

then

```
.contenu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 622px;
    position: relative;
    top: -363px;
    left: 265px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

to

```
.contenu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 622px;
    float: right;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

then change your footer to this:

```
footer
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
p, li
{
 text-align: justify;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                             POLICES                                                */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ambleregular';
    src: url('Amble-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Amble-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Amble-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Amble-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Amble-Regular-webfont.svg#ambleregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                         CORPS DE LA PAGE                                           */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.police
{
    font-family: 'ambleregular', "Times New Roman", Georgia, Arial, Verdana, "Courier New", sans-serif;
}

#Bloc_principal
{
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: purple;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                             EN - TETE                                              */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

header
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}

#logo img
{
    width:56px;
    height: auto;
    border:2px black solid;
    float: left;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                MENU                                                */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.menu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.menu_perso
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu_cote
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu_perso ul, .menu_cote ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

aside
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

footer
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    clear: both;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                CORPS                                               */
/*                                                                                                    */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.contenu
{
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 622px;
    float: right;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>GE-tools</title>
    </head>

    <body class="police">
     <div id="Bloc_principal">
      <header>
       <div id="logo">
        <img src="GE_tool.PNG" alt="Logo">
       </div>
       <h1 class="titre_principal">GE-Tools</h1>
      </header>

      <section class="menu">
       <nav class="menu_perso">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">My Mails</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>

       <nav class="menu_cote">
        <h1>Tools</h1>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">bbbbbbbbbbb</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ccccccccccc</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ddddddddddd</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">eeeeeeeeeee</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">fffffffffff</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>

       <aside>
        <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
       </aside>
      </section> 
      <section class="contenu">
       <h1>Welcome in GE-tool</h1>

       <p>Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem sed sibi vicissim velut ad perpendiculum aemulas: Caesaream, quam ad honorem Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas.</p>

       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

 
                At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>

       <p>Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem sed sibi vicissim ad honorem Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas.</p>
      </section>

      <footer>
       <p>Copyright GE - Tools corporation 2017©</p>
      </footer>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately if I want a margin between top and right of 10 px and if I add margin: 10px in .contenu it makes a big hole between header and section. What should I do then ?

Comment: Should be no problem then, if I understood you correctly. Just add `margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px` inside `.menu` and `margin-top: 10px` inside `.contenu`. Also don't forget to add `clear:both` inside your `footer` for clearing the floats and not mess up your structure, see explanation [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/). And check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lae8t6df/) for the changes I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're building this is broken. You have `top: -363px;` on `.contenu` and that's the reason footer is so low. The position is shifted but technically that space is still occupied. You never declared `absolute` positioning for that element, which would take it out of the flow.

However, all of this is the wrong way to build such a layout regardless. You can do this with flexbox or floated elements.